# Changing network and DHCP Scope from /24 to /23 for new users

Tags: networking, router, dhcp

I have watchguard XTM VPN Firewall(use as internet gateway) with /24 and DHCP Server (192.168.1.2 to 1.250) at office. Nowadays we are facing problem like not enough ip address so i want to change to /23 network so that I can have enough ip for new users. As our servers and gateway running live,

Shall I Configure Watchguard ip to 192.168.1.253/23 network first then change DHCP scope to (192.168.0.2 to 1.250) or Just change just change DHCP scope only?

Thank you.

Comment: you will need to change the router LAN IP as you suggest, because otherwise, the interface will not be able to contact the hosts in the .0.1 - .0.255 range without a route to them, as it will believe that that is a differant network. the hosts in the affected network would be able to send requests to the internet, but the router could not return the responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your plan, set your WatchGuard to use the /23 prefix length (subnet mask 255.255.254.0).

You should be able to change the DHCP scope at the same time, if your new configuration becomes effective all at once.  However, if there was something to do first, it would be to set the WatchGuard's subnet first, and then adjust the DHCP scope later.

If you try to hand out DHCP addresses that are outside of the subnet that you are using, then that might cause an error, or it might work.  But if it works, the device that gets the IP address wouldn't be able to have two-way communication with the WatchGuard if the WatchGuard isn't listening for traffic.  This will destroy Internet connectivity if the WatchGuard is your default gateway, which I suspect is the intended plan.  That's why the WatchGuard's subnet should be changed first.